# SwiftUI: I want to reduce the spacing between the sections in this list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

The goal is to have the two sections in the list separate, but closer together, nearly touching; about a 16px gap. The design of the default list is what is wanted for the design.

I have tried using `.listRowInsets(top: , .leading: , .bottom: , .trailing: )`, but that just screws up view of the GoPremium() button, cutting off the image, etc.

I tried placing GoPremium() outside the List but in the VStack, but then the background does not match the rest of the list(which is the intended background for the design). It also does not conform to the frame I want, being too wide. `.frame(width: 382, height: 140` It seems like there's a point where the image won't get any less wide, unless it is put in the List.

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @State var pageSelected: String?
    @State var pages: [String] = ["Add your own", "Notifications", "About", "Instagram", "Twitter", "Email", "Terms of Service", "Privacy Policy"]
            
    var footer: some View {
        Text("footer")
            .font(.body).fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            .padding(.bottom)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                GoPremium()
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
            ForEach(pages, id: \.self) { item in
                Button {
                    self.pageSelected = item
                } label: {
                    Text(item)
                        .font(.callout).fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollDisabled(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .large)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: BackButton())
        .overlay(footer)
    }
}
```

The gap between the GoPremium() section and the ForEach loop is too big.

GoPremium() is a struct containing a button:

```
struct GoPremium: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
            } label: {
                Image("goPremium")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .overlay(
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
                            Text("Go Premium")
                                .font(.title2).fontWeight(.bold)
                            Text("Access all **********, ******, *****, and remove ads!")
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                .shadow(radius: 1, x: 0, y: 3)
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.white))
            }
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .shadow(radius: 3, x: 0, y: 5)
            Spacer(minLength: 7)
        }
    }
}
```